# Converting Html Template to Thymeleaf Template

Tags: html, css, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, template-engine

I am trying to convert my html5 template for my spring project. In this project i use thymeleaf template. In order to convert, i changed all scripts src into th:src or all style files (css files to) th:href etc. But design seems wrong.

```
<script th:src="@{/resources/js/jquery.min.js}" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Fonts -->
<link th:href="@{http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,400italic,700}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link th:href="@{http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico}" href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link th:href="@{/resources/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css}" href='font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link th:href="@{/resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Main Style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/resources/style.css}" href="style.css" />

<!-- owl Style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/resources/css/owl.carousel.css}" href="css/owl.carousel.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/resources/css/owl.transitions.css}" href="css/owl.transitions.css" />
```

```
<!-- rating -->
<script th:src="@{/resources/js/rate/jquery.raty.js}" src="js/rate/jquery.raty.js"></script>
<script th:src="@{/resources/js/labs.js}" src="js/labs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/resources/js/product/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js}" src="js/product/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- fancybox -->
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/resources/js/product/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5}" src="js/product/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<!-- custom js -->
<script th:src="@{/resources/js/shop.js}" src="js/shop.js"></script>
```

These are the converted tags. And also when i execute my page i get the exception shown below. This image is not exist in my bootstrap/img folder also it is not exist in template folder as well. But template seems to work without Thymeleaf.

```
jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5:1994 GET http://localhost:8080/resources/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: it does not get processed by thymeleaf. The _th:src_ should replace the _src_ attributes. Did you really integrate thymeleaf in your application? http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#integrating-thymeleaf-with-spring

Comment: I already did this. But some files works well some don't it seems

Comment: do they have a different path (prefix or suffix) that may not match the configuration? I know it would be a simple solution but sometimes this are the overseen errors ;) The last problem is bootstrap related. Bootstrap ships with glyphicons font that got referenced here. But first you should solve the basic thymeleaf problem.

Answer (score 0):

For those resources with "http://" prefix, no need to use th:href.
For those inner-site resources, "/resources/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png", please remove "/resources", Spring Framework will append it by default.

Below is from Spring document for your reference.
By default Spring will serve static content from a directory called /static (or /public or /
resources or /META-INF/resources) in the classpath or from the root of the ServletContext.
It uses the ResourceHttpRequestHandler from Spring MVC so you can modify that behavior by
adding your own WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and overriding the addResourceHandlers method.